# django google calendar API and south freeze issue

Tags: django, google-api, google-oauth, django-south

I'm trying to use the Google API django [client lib](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django).  In order to store the credentials for each user of my web app, a Credentials model is set up:

```
from oauth2client.django_orm import CredentialsField
class CredentialsModel(models.Model):
  id = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
  credential = CredentialsField()
```

However upon trying to add this model with a South migration, I get:

```
Cannot freeze field 'google.credentialsmodel.credential'
(this field has class oauth2client.django_orm.CredentialsField)

South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
models parser (it often broke things).
To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
```

I read the linked document, but I'm not much clearer on how to fix this.  How do I write introspection rules? or how do I fix this to simply add the model with this funky field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines before your model declaration:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^oauth2client\.django_orm\.CredentialsField"])
```

That will allow South to know about the `oauth2client.django_orm.CredentialField` and to use the introspection rules defined by its parent class.